# Font hierarchy and ability to detect user machine font within CSS? Are there font hierarchies inside CSS?

Tags: css, fonts

A UX designer at my company has provided me a list of fonts, that he describes as a hierarchy.
The list of fonts I was given were:

"font-family:
"Palatino Linotype", "Times New Roman", Times, "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif"

The logic being that we'll assume those fonts are pre-loaded on the user's machine and that if one isn't available it goes down the list to the next one.

I have not heard of this in CSS before.  I'm aware one can customize font family, but I thought that involved loading up a ttf file.

Can someone point me to a resource on how to direct such a hierarchy of native texts on a computer?
Or is my designer full of it?

Comment: I doubt that there is a browser without `Times New Roman`, the code after it is meaningless and very bad because it consumes resources.

Comment: "The font-family property can hold several font names as a "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font." Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

Comment: @Claudiu how does it consumes resources? I would understand if it was a `@font-face`, but local fonts too? Also what if the user has uninstalled the font on his/her computer? (there's people that like living dangerously :P)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro , so, the font-family provides the back up in case the first specific font isn't available?  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp  provides slightly more detail.  Looks like my origin CSS was clumsy syntax but that I could clean it up and still have that fallback listing of several sytaxes.  Thankyou, this has been helpful.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro In the same way as writing `0px` is **wrong** because it consumes resources. You should write `0`. I never saw such a long declaration for `font-family`, that's why I doubt it is best practice.

Comment: Writing `0px` is **not wrong**: `After a zero length, the unit identifier is optional` (source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units). It may look better or not (I personally find strange having all numeric values with units and suddenly a `0`) but it's not wrong. As per the resources: true, it's wasting 2 characters; they may end up adding to a lot more if you are working in big projects, but at that point you should probably be using CSS minifiers. For the font, you are wasting more characters, but you never know if some "crazy user" has uninstalled a default font.